# Does GWT supporting types conversion?

Tags: java, gwt

I am wondering if GWT supports types conversion? I know that the Vaadin have such support. I mean something like Vaadin StringToIntegerConverter and all this stuff mentioned here: https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/datamodel/datamodel-properties.html

I am totally new in GWT, but I haven't found even a word about this issue in framework documentation. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though Vaadin converters you're referring to serve the specific purpose of binding models to presenters, if you're looking for a way to, for example, initialize an integer from a string, GWT [emulates](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html) classes wrapping java primitives (Integer, Double, etc.). Methods of these classes allow you to do, e.g., this:

```
int myInt = new Integer(myString).intValue();
```

Comment: Could you tell me if I am think in right way- there is no automatic way to bind request to data model in GWT? Or maybe there is some other way to do that and I don't need this type of binding?

Comment: Not in GWT proper. There might be third party libraries but I'm not sure which one suits your needs best.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I want hear :)

Answer (score 0):

GWT has a [JRE Emulation](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html) and provide a lot of Classes and methods.

You can call `Integer.valueOf("666")` to get a `666`